# Replacing IFrame with div

Tags: php, iframe, html

I have a IFrame where I load in a custom search, and display the results within the iframe. The search results I obtain by calling an external url, that returns a value. I need to implement the same thing for a mobi site that works on mobile devices, and thus I need to replace the IFrame with something else. Will this be possible using a div tag, since most mobile devices do not support frames. And no javascript may be used. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the content directly on the page when it is initially built.

Since you say it is external, this will probably involve using [curl](http://php.net/curl) to fetch the content, parsing it, extracting the content (discarding the `<head>` for instance) and inserting it onto the page.

Note that this is stepping into even hotter copyright waters then iframing content from an external site — so make sure the data provider is happy for you to do this.

(Or use an `<object type="text/html">` which is effectively an `<iframe>` with worse browser support)